# PagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiate

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am trying to create tabs in my android activity,I have done this before,used the same type implementation for this method also

Now in my Activity class in this line **final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());**
I have an error **PagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiate** I don't know what does that mean

Here is my Activity class code

```html
package com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_turmeric.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_turmeric.R;

public class PestsHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pests_home);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.diseases));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.insectpescts));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.bioagents));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Then there is another thing in my Adapter class I cannot return my final tab "tab3" it says **Required android.support.v4.app.Fragment;**
but i have imported that already

here is my adapter class code

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_turmeric.view.TabFragment1;
import com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_turmeric.view.TabFragment2;
import com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_turmeric.view.TabFragment3;


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
```

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is, you have named you customize adapter as `PagerAdapter` which is also an existing API in android [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).

So remove the import

```
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
```

and carefully import your pageradapter package

Note : It's recommended to avoid naming your classes same as android API